# Image and setInterval syncing: Display an image when if() is true?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, setinterval

**Background**

I am using an interval (`setInterval`) to increment a time stamp in order to recreate a timeline (1954-1956). Once my time stamp is greater than a certain unix time stamp, I want some string and an image to be parsed.

I prepared a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Naibaf/nvnn9186/2/) (https://jsfiddle.net/Naibaf/nvnn9186/2/) to showcase my problem. Please press the play button to start the interval.

**Problem**

With javascript if-statements, I succeed regarding the string...

```
if (timeStamp > 19902) {
$('#su').html("SU");
}
if (timeStamp > 20694) {
$('#gb').html("GB");
}
```

...however, I do not know how to get the images AT THE SAME TIME as the string.

**What I want**

Make the images appear at the same time as the string. (in my JSFiddle example, RU and GB)

**Question**

*Can I parse my images by fulfilling a Javascript if-statement?*

Comment: It's kind-of unclear what you mean by "parse" here.

Comment: Thanks. I mean to display. Is it clear now?

Comment: Yes. For future reference, the words "parse" and "display" have completely different meanings :)

Comment: Cheers, let me edit that. Can you also answer my question? :)

Comment: So you want the images to be hidden at the start, and then to show when the time is appropriate? Can't you just use `.hide()` and `.show()` at the same time you update the text?

Comment: That's correct. Never heard of .hide() and .show() before. So, if my understanding is correct, I would need to .hide() my images on default and .show() them when the if-statement is TRUE. Yes?

Comment: [altered fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u5wa78r4/)

Comment: Exactly, how I liked it to work. I'll confirm your reply as the answer, if you change comment to answer. Thanks, Pointy!